# Script to find number of zip file in folder

Tags: windows, script, windows-server-2008

I need a script that counts the number of .zip (zip files ends with monday_abc.zip) files in a folder on windows 2008 server.

Is it also possible to find the last modified zip files and the number of files in the last modified zip file ?

Comment: are you running the locally or remotely?

Answer (score 5):

With PowerShell, you could essentially do this even as a one-liner.

```
$items = Get-ChildItem | sort LastModifiedTime -Descending | Where-Object {$_.Extension -eq ".zip"}
```

Then for how many files were found:

```
$items.length
```

And for the last modified items:

```
$items[0]
```